# Clone web component nested other not work - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, web

I trying to work with web component in Vanilla Js without React or other Framework and I create some web component like this:

```
const actionBlock = document.createElement('action_block');
actionBlock.innerHTML = 

<li id="act_{0}">
    <div class="wf-item wf-item-first">
        <div class="wf-line-sep"></div>
        <div class="wf-element">
            <div class="wf-delete-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></div>
            <div class="wf-item wf-item-first">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-wrench icon-standard"></i>
                <span class="unselectable">

                    Define Action

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wf-item wf-item-first">
        <div class="wf-line-sep"></div>
        <button class="wf-plus-btn">
            <div class="wf-plus-inside">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
            </div>
        </button>
    </div>
</li>;

class ActionBlock extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        
        this.innerHTML = actionBlock.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace("{0}", this.getAttribute("data-id"));
        
    }

    render() {
    }

}
window.customElements.define('action-block', ActionBlock);



<action-block data-id="1"></action-block>
```

My problem is to clone and after to append some component nested each other. Example:

```
<component1 id="1">
    <component2>
         <component3>
         </component3>
    </component2>
</component1>
```

In this case I try to get all component with document.querySelector("#1").clone(true) and after to append it in new DIV .

After to append it I have this situation:

```
<div id="newDiv">
    <component1 id="1">
         
    </component1>
</div>
```

The web components nested inside the first not rendered. Also I try to create a new component and add the all innerHtml, but not work yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using the [Shadow DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) with [`<slot>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) correctly may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to use "insertAdjacentHTML":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

```js
var element = document.getElementById('wrapper');
element.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "afterbegin",
  "<span style='color:white; background-color: black;'>This is Example</span>"
);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this method but I have the same result: the parent component is added correctly but the other nested not insert.